# Prove that Cov$(\sum_{k=j}^\infty \rho^k e_{t-k}, \sum_{k=0}^\infty \rho^k e_{t-j-k} ) = \rho^j \frac{\sigma^2}{1-\rho^2}$, where $e_t$ white noise

Tags: covariance

Let $e_t$ be a white noise, in other words:

- E$e_t = 0$,
- Cov$(e_t, e_{t'})=0$, when $t \not = t'$,
- Var$(e_t) = \sigma^2$ (do not depends on time t)

Let $|\rho| < 1$, $ j>0 $ be constants.

How to prove that

Cov$(\sum_{k=j}^\infty \rho^k e_{t-k}, \sum_{k=0}^\infty \rho^k e_{t-j-k} ) 
= \rho^j \frac{\sigma^2}{1-\rho^2}$.

When I tried to prove it, I stucked with two infinity sums product. Any help would be truly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{align}
Cov(\sum_{k=j}^\infty \rho^k e_{t-k}, \sum_{k=0}^\infty \rho^k e_{t-j-k} )&=Cov(\sum_{k=j}^\infty \rho^k e_{t-k}, \sum_{k=j}^\infty \rho^{k-j} e_{t-k} )\\
&=\rho^{-j}Cov(\sum_{k=j}^\infty \rho^k e_{t-k}, \sum_{k=j}^\infty \rho^{k} e_{t-k} )\\
&=\rho^{-j}var(\sum_{k=j}^\infty \rho^k e_{t-k})\\
&=\rho^{-j}\sum_{k=j}^\infty var( \rho^k e_{t-k})\\
&=\rho^{-j}\sum_{k=j}^\infty  \rho^{2k} \sigma^2\\
&=\frac{\rho^{j}}{1-\rho^2} \sigma^2\\
\end{align}

---

Using $k+j \to k'$ we have 
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=0}^\infty \rho^k e_{t-j-k}&=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \rho^{(k+j)-j}e_{t-(j+k)}\\
&=\sum_{k'=j}^\infty \rho^{k'-j}  e_{t-k'}\\
&=\rho^{-j}\sum_{k'=j}^\infty \rho^{k'}  e_{t-k'}\\
\end{align}

Comment: thank you very much for the answer! Can you please explain, how do you obtain first equality?

Comment: sure, see the edit :-) I also corrected a little typo.

Comment: Thank you very much for a such clear and good answer! :-)

Comment: you are welcome :-)